# Iterating through list to find max and swapping it to front

Tags: python

The question exactly is: Create a function (jumpMaximum) that, given any list of integers list, returns a list with the same elements as list,
except that the first element has been swapped with the maximum element in list.
Note: This function should not print the list, but return it.
My code so far is:

```
def jumpMaximum (list):
    maximum= list[0]
    for i in range(len(list)):
        for j in range(len(list)):    
            if i>j and i>maximum:
                maximum=i
                maximum, list[0] = list[0], maximum
    return list
print(jumpMaximum([1,2,3,4]))
```

Now when I run this, I get [3, 2, 3, 4], but this is wrong of course. I made the for loops to iterate through the list and find the maximum. And then I wrote //maximum, list[0] = list[0], maximum// to swap the first element with the max, so I am not sure where it is going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
def jump_maximum(lst):
    _, i = max((e, i) for i, e in enumerate(lst))
    lst[0], lst[i] = lst[i], lst[0]
    return lst


print(jump_maximum([1, 2, 3, 4]))
```

**Output**

```
[4, 2, 3, 1]
```

The idea is to use [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) in conjunction with [max](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) to find the index (`i`) of the maximum element, then simply swap the elements and return the list.

As a *side note* you should not use names such as list for your variables because it shadows the built-in [list](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list).

**UPDATE**

If you cannot use `enumerate` or `max`, you can do it like this:

```
def jump_maximum(lst):

    i, ma = 0, lst[0]
    for j in range(len(lst)):
        if lst[j] > ma:
            ma = lst[j]
            i = j

    lst[0], lst[i] = lst[i], lst[0]
    return lst


print(jump_maximum([1, 2, 3, 4]))
```

**Output**

```
[4, 2, 3, 1]
```

The idea is to substitute `enumerate` and `max` by the `for` loop. Also you don't need the nested loops.

Comment: Thanks, however I cannot use any built-in function like max() or enumerate(). Also now I did the line you did of // lst[0], lst[i] = lst[i], lst[0]// but now it outputs //[4, 2, 1, 3]// whereas that order is scrambled, I need for it to be [4,2,3,1].

Comment: @itiswhatitis Updated the answer!

Comment: @itiswhatitis Glad I could help! If my answer helped to solve your problem, please consider [marking it as accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/195035). That's the customary way of indicating that your question is "resolved" and thanking the person who helped you.